# "Village of X" or Village in X"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Say, I want to talk about village that belongs to a particular city. How to express it:

The village of X in Y
or
The village of X of Y

And my confusion also applies to a population belonging to some city:

The people of X
or
The people of Y

Which is the correct option?

Comment: In what was does the village "belong" to a particular city? Is it a suburb of that city?

Comment: You mean like: Greenwich Village in the Borough of Manhattan in the City of New York?  I would probably say "in" not "of".

Comment: Yes, definitely! So "in" is true, eh? What about the "people of the village" vs "people in the village"? Do you sense any difference?

Comment: @Reactor4 "Greenwich Village" is a name, not a descriptor (it was a descriptor hundreds of years ago when the village was outside the city proper, but now GV is simply a neighborhood).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UK English would use "in" to set a rural village in its County.

"XXing in  YY-shire." "XX-ing in the County of YY-shire."

*To place a village close to a Town you would find*:

"YY-ton and the nearby village of YY-ing."
" ...from XX-ton.  In the adjacent village off YY-ham there are..."

In your second case the inhabitants are "from Wells," or the "people of Wells are known for..." or "farmers in Tavistock are known for their..."

Comment: Oh thanks! Can we also say "farmers of the city"? I think I might have heard something like that before...

Comment: @Reactor4 That's an interesting one.  You can't say farmers of London, or farmers of Birmingham: it would be farmers of the South-East, or Midlands farmers, or 'farmers supplying L or B.'  But you could certainly say farmers of Hereford, or any city with farmland nearby.Truro, St Davids, Are there rural and urban areas where that makes sense?